# Break the cycle of sounds. How to fix?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I made a sound in the list on the button.

```
int i = 0;
...
void nextTrack(int i)
    {   
        mSound = new int [] {
                R.raw.error_one, 
                R.raw.error_two, 
                R.raw.error_three
                };
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), mSound[i]);      
        mp.start();
    }
...
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
nextTrack(i);
i++;
}
```

But after the sound R.raw.error_three, the application crashes.

UPD.: I need to after the third sound again sounded the first

Logs.:[image]

Comment: but you have only Three elements in your Array so you have to check `if(i < mSound.length())`

Comment: Can you show the lagcat messages?

Comment: to M D: Cannot invoke length() on the array type int[]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of bounds exception, because there is no `mSound[3]`, only 0-2, total 3 elements.

```
void nextTrack(int i) {   
    mSound = new int [] {
                R.raw.error_one, 
                R.raw.error_two, 
                R.raw.error_three
                };
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), mSound[i % 3]);      
    mp.start();
}
```

You can use `i % 3` to replace `i` in `nextTrack` method, so the sound play by loop( sound[0], sound[1], sound[2], sound[0].... )

Use `i % 3`, so the value will always be `0`, `1` or `2`.

See [official doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) of the `%` operator.

Comment: Nice one, dont forget to release() your not used MediaPlayer when you are creating a new one each click, or you might end up with a memory leak

Comment: mp.release() in every Click?

Answer (score 0):

Your need put condition in your `onClick()`, here you need to make sure array index should always be less than the length of the array

```
               @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(i < mSound.length){
                        nextTrack(i);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Eclipse tells 
 Cannot invoke length() on the array type int[]

Comment: typo check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you want to play Sound 1 after Sound three again. Then just add something like this :

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    nextTrack(i);
                    i++;
                    if(i > mSound.length)
                        i = 0;
                }
            }
```